# MongoDB расширение для PHP 7.1 на FreeBSD

Tags: mongodb, freebsd, php7, pecl

Команда `pkg install pecl-mongodb` пытается тянуть в зависимостях пакет php56. Вангую, что и установится она тоже для него. Тогда как у меня уже php71 стоит и работает в связке с nginx. Как мне поставить расширение mongodb для моей версии PHP? Сборка из портов не пугает, но желательно бы поставить пакетом. Если пойти другим путём (`pecl install mongodb`) то вопрос как во фряшку правильно ставится `pear` или `pecl`? Пакетов `php71-pear` или `php71-dev` мне `pkg search php71` не выдал. Как быть?

P.S. FreeBSD-11.1-RELEASE

Comment: Подозреваю, сборка `databases/pecl-mongodb` из портов решит проблему.

Comment: @arrowd это да. Но, как я писал выше, хотелось бы по возможности обойтись пакетами. Если уж совсем, как говорится, дело зайдёт в тупик, тогда из портов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо собрать порт `databases/pecl-mongodb`.

Пакеты собираются из портов, а версия PHP по умолчанию сейчас установлена в 5.6. Поэтому все pecl- пакеты так же собираются для версии 5.6. На самом деле, собрать из портов в данном случае совсем не страшно, т.к. ничего дополнительного затянуться не должно.

Если хотите совсем уж "правильное" решение - установите `poudriere`, соберите с помощью него собственный репозиторий пакетов с PHP 7, и добавьте его в `pkg`.

UPDATE:

В дереве портов появились FLAVORS, которые позволяют собирать один и тот же порт под разные версии зависимостей. Благодаря этому, теперь этот пакет можно поставить командой `pkg install php71-pecl-mongodb`.